# Manifold path components are open

Tags: general-topology

Can someone explain why the path components of a manifold are open? I'm a little confused at how to demonstrate this fact and it would obviously help me understand manifolds better.

Comment: Is path component of manifold related to the disconnected component of manifold?

Comment: And is the set of path component of manifold, equivalent to the set of disconnected component of manifold?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Manifolds are locally homeomorphic to Euclidean balls, and so simply connected and path connected, and pretty much whatever you want.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Andreas Blass--I misread your question, my previous response would have been if you asked whether or not the connected components of a manifold are open.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Youcis's answer is true, but I think "locally pathwise connected" is more useful for this question.

Answer (score -1):

A manifold is locally euclidean implies it is locally path connected. Hence components and path components are the same and they are open.